# Can I place the MUA vent directly beneath the range?

Tags: hvac, kitchens

In California, I'd like to upgrade my range hood and may require make up air.

I've seen these installed in the toe kicks of kitchen cabinets. Would it be acceptable to install registers directly beneath the range itself?